# How to get latitudes and longitudes from google map in ionic 2?

Tags: cordova, google-maps, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app, angular2-services

I am trying to integrate google map in my ionic 2 hybrid mobile application but i'm in trouble with getting latitudes and longitudes of any place when point the location from google map.

Comment: did you found solution for this.Please let me know, I am also stuck with this issue. I have looked into many blog but non seems to be fruitfull tnx

Answer (score 1):

step 1; install this one  `ionic plugin add --save cordova-plugin-geolocation` and `npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation` .

step2:

Import the `import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';` inside your app.module.ts file and add it to your `providers array`,

step3:
    Add the below code in your respected .ts file and then the `resp`is an object which will give you the lat and long value of your current location

```
   this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
 // resp.coords.latitude
 // resp.coords.longitude
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error getting location', error);
});
```

Note:

> You should check in your real device inorder to get the exact lat and long value

for more info check this [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) but I need latitudes and longitudes while select location any where in the map.Not the current location.

Comment: @AsbarAli then you should have ask the question clearly

Comment: In my question include '"getting latitudes and longitudes of any place when point the location from google map". it means, not the current location.However thank you for your response :).

Comment: where ever you want to get the lat and long you should be needing this peace of code so try to add the this code in side the map what ever you wanted then check

Comment: I added it, but it always gives the current location :(.

Comment: using the above loctaion plugin code you will always get the current location only you can not get anyother lan and long value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704357/geolocation-not-working-in-device-ionic3  @MohanGopi help!!

Answer (score 0):

have a look at following 2 blog post form Josh Morony, these will answer your question.
[https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/]
[https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-advanced-google-maps-component-in-ionic-2/]

Comment: I followed those tutorials and couldn't find any code related to retrieve latitudes & longitudes when point the location.