# Geolocation not working in device ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, geolocation, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working with ionic 3 location-based work. I am not able to get current location of latitude and longitude here. I mentioned my usable code. It's working fine in browser level but not working in a mobile device.

code

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation --variable GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="To locate you"
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation
```

```js
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {}

this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
  console.log( resp.coords.latitude)
 console.log( resp.coords.longitude)
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error getting location', error);
});
```

Comment: @Suraj Rao i can't understand

Comment: I edited your question the best I could. Let me know if I got something wrong..

Comment: no no correct everything is fine u have any idea @SurajRao

Comment: try to set the geolocation call inside `this.platform.ready().then(()=>{})`. Also is the call inside the constructor?

Comment: same not wokring @SurajRao

Comment: where exactly are you calling `this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`?

Comment: ionViewDidLoad() @Suraj Rao

Comment: is it throwing error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

//Set the properties in this class
long: any; //longitude
lati: any; //latitude

constructor(private platform: Platform, private geolocation: Geolocation) {
this.platform.ready().then(()=>{

//set options.. 
var options = {
           timeout: 20000 //sorry I use this much milliseconds
       }
//use the geolocation 
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(data=>{
  this.long = data.coords.longitude;
  this.lati = data.coords.latitude;
 }).catch((err)=>{
     console.log("Error", err);
   });
});
}
```

Let this be in the constructor. Don't forget to agree to the location privacy permission, also enable location option on your Android device(this is probable though).

Comment: in what purpose we give timeout ?@frnac

Comment: @jose **timeout** is one of the optional parameters that you can pass to the getCurrentPosition() method.  It is measured in milliseconds. Timeout is important because it lets your request run for the duration that you have stated before letting it pass to the next line which is the console error. 

The more the timeout, the more the request is lengthened however, more device resources are consumed.

Answer (score 2):

Try to call the geolocation function inside ionViewDidLoad() or ngAfterViewInit() method.

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {}

ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
    console.log( resp.coords.latitude)
    console.log( resp.coords.longitude)
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error getting location', error);
  });
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem!

Comment: i am getting error like this position:Only secure origins are allowed (see: goo.gl/Y0ZkNV)

Comment: Dont try it on web browser. Use mobile device or emulator to test.

Comment: i am using mobile device browser is working fine in device iam getting error

Comment: Gunawardhana any idea?

Comment: nope bro.. could not identify .. If i could find anything, I will comment

Comment: get any solution? @Sarasa

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

//Set the properties in this class
long: any; //longitude
lati: any; //latitude

constructor(private platform: Platform, private geolocation: Geolocation) {
this.platform.ready().then(()=>{

//set options.. 
var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 60000, maximumAge: 0
    };
//use the geolocation 
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(data=>{
  this.long = data.coords.longitude;
  this.lati = data.coords.latitude;
 }).catch((err)=>{
     console.log("Error", err);
   });

 let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition(options);
          watch.subscribe((data) => {
            let lat_lng = data.coords.latitude+","+data.coords.longitude; 

});

});
}
```